# MongoDB Compound Index Prefix with Sort

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes, compound-index

I have trouble deciding where to best put sorting field in a mongodb compound index.

My understanding is that we need to choose the highest cardinality & selectivity as the preceeding fields in a compound index

```
db.person.createIndex({ rating: 1, name: 1, gender: 1});
```

For this example, rating only ranges from  1 to 5 and gender is M or F
So, name is always the highest cardinality & selectivity and should be the leftmost field in the compound index; however, the use case for query is such that rating is always provided in the query, and either name or gender can optionally be provided via filter in the application.

Which option is best for this case:

1)

```
db.person.createIndex({ rating: 1, name: 1, gender: 1});
```

2)

```
db.person.createIndex({ rating: 1});
db.person.createIndex({ name: 1, gender: 1});
db.person.createIndex({ gender: 1});
```

Comment: What field are you trying to sort on?

Comment: the rating is always provided for sorting

Comment: It is difficult to say anything without actually trying some real queries and sample datasets with different indexes. In general, since the `rating` is used for query filter and also for sorting _always_, the index { rating: 1, name: 1, gender: 1} can be considered as the main candidate. Query plans (using `explain`) will provide sufficient info to make a decision. Also, see MongoDB docs topics on using compound indexes for sorting: [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/index.html#sort-and-index-prefix).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Find performance: single compound index VS two single field indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893613/mongodb-find-performance-single-compound-index-vs-two-single-field-indexes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these indexes:

```js
// supports query with rating and gender specified
db.person.createIndex({ rating: 1, gender: 1});

// supports query with rating and name (and optionally gender) specified
db.person.createIndex({ name: 1, rating: 1, gender: 1});
```